Should i use multiple gitlab runners or a single gitlab runner with request_concurrency set to a value?
I have a setup where all the runners are untagged, use the same executor(docker). In this case which is more efficient in terms of cpu and memory usage?

4 gitlab runners
Single gitlab runner with request_concurrency set to 4

In terms of executor both the options seems to be creating 4 containers at a time, so i wanted to know if the runner itself consumes certain level of cpu / ram for its operation which increases with the number of runners.

I don't know but you should prefer 4 gitlab runners in case one of them is down it will not impact the whole
